# What is the shortcut for "Find the word at caret" in Android Studio for Mac

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I see no shortcut key in Android Studio for "Find Word at Caret" (see 5th row below).

[image]

However when I searched [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/finding-word-at-caret.html) documents I have found this.

[image]

I know the first option but I didn't understand the second one. What is <kbd>N/A</kbd> keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [page you are referring to](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/finding-word-at-caret.html) uses JavaScript to dynamically change content depending on reader's environment.

In case of OS X it changes to <kbd>N/A</kbd> meaning simply: **Not Available** (or "not applicable").

```
        <span class="menupath">Edit | Find | Find Word At Caret</span>.
    </li><li class="list__item">
        Use
        <kbd data-default="Ctrl+F3" data-default_for_gnome="Ctrl+F3" data-default_for_kde="Ctrl+3" data-default_for_xwin="Ctrl+F3" data-emacs="Ctrl+F3" data-jbuilder="Ctrl+F3" data-visual_studio="Ctrl+F3" data-netbeans_6.5="N/A" data-eclipse="Ctrl+F12" data-mac_os_x_10.5_="N/A" data-mac_os_x="&#x2318;F3" data-eclipse_mac_os_x="N/A" data-intellij_idea_classic_os_x="N/A" data-xcode="N/A" data-resharper="N/A" data-resharper_osx="N/A">Ctrl+F3</kbd>
        keyboard shortcut.
```

As for the shortcut itself you can create your own by going to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

Comment: I thought it could be "not applicable" but got confused as it was another option. May be there's a key in another environment. Thanks for the answer.